# Cannot get the current user ID from an SQL statement using Razor in WebMatrix

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-ce, razor, webmatrix

I'm learning razor syntax, using the startersite in WebMatrix and trying to display some data from a table. I want to select only the data from the logged in user, so in effect want to say

```
...WHERE UserId =@WebSecurity.CurrentUserId";
```

but that doesn't work.

Using the @0 method doesn't work for me either - I get an 'A parameter is missing. [ Parameter ordinal = 1 ]' error.

Do I have to set a variable then use the @0 / @1 / @whichever way? If so - what's wrong with this code?

```
@{
//Is the user logged in?
WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

//Get the user's data

var TheUser = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

   var db= Database.Open("StarterSite");
   var sqlQ = "SELECT * FROM Days WHERE UserId =@0";
   var data = db.Query(sqlQ);
   }
```

I'm sure this is very much a beginners issue but I'm just trying to get started. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the value to the query
[documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.query%28VS.99%29.aspx)

```
var data = db.Query(sqlQ, TheUser);
```